# Material ui tabs not scrollable on mobile view

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Material ui tabs scroll not working on mobile view**

I tried to put the following

```
      variant="scrollable"
      scrollButtons="auto"
```

Here's the snippet of my code

```
          subheader={(
            <Tabs scrollButtons="on" variant="scrollable" value={activeTab} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}>
              <Tab key="Overview" activetab={0} label="Overview" />
              <Tab key="Followers" activetab={1} label={getTabCount('Followers', facets.followers)} />
            ....
            </Tabs>
          )}
```

**Update:**

Looks like it's an existing issue. When we toggle to the mobile mode, you will be able to see the issue.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gdrfp?file=/demo.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/22598

Reference: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

Comment: Only two tabs.... do they already fit into the viewport? I don't believe the scrolling arrows will display unless there's more content to scroll into view.

Comment: We have around 4 tabs. One of the tab is cut off as we are trying to render it in mobile view as well. Hence trying to have a scrolling option

Comment: I see. Can you update your question to include for us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can review?

Comment: Updated. But it looks like an existing issue in github based on further research.

Comment: I see, and yeah, looks to be a known issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get response from the material UI team.

This will be fixed in material UI 5 - https://next.material-ui.com/

Example for v5 on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2yw9t?file=/demo.js:0-2159&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Answer (score 0):

Using version `@mui/material@5.15.3`, there's a property to display the scrolling arrows, named `allowScrollButtonsMobile`:

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  variant="scrollable"
  scrollButtons="auto"
  allowScrollButtonsMobile
>
[...]
</Tabs>
```